# Why does the "intersectLine" method in Java give me a false result?

Tags: java, computational-geometry, rectangles

For a personal project in Java, I have to determine whether a line segment intersects the interior of a rectangle. I used the Rectangle2D.Double from java.awt.geom, but apparently the "intersectsLine" method, which should do precisely what I want, does not give correct results.

Here is sample code:

```
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;

public class test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Rectangle2D.Double r = new Rectangle2D.Double(2, 7, 5, 1);
        System.out.println(r.intersectsLine(4, 8, 1, 8));
    }

}
```

This surprisingly prints out "true". I cannot understand this behavior. I checked the documentation and the Rectangle constructor expects the coordinates of the upper left corner and then the width and height. Then the rectangle "r" should lie below the line (4,8)-(1,8), so they cannot intersect.

Is this a bug or a mistake on my side?

Comment: Is it correct to say, that the corners of the rectangles are `(2,7)`, `(7,7)`, `(7,8)` and `(2,8)` or am I missing something here?

Comment: Is the Y axis down->up or up->down? That's very important. Asked differently: where's the origin of your coordinate system, at the bottom or at the top-right corner of your screen? Does the height extend upwards or downwards? If it extends upwards, your line is intersecting (it lies exactly on the upper border then)

Comment: I mean "top-left" of course *facepalm*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The coordinate system the `java.awt.geom` package is using puts the origin `(0,0)` in the top left corner and the Y values are increasing downwards. Check the documentation on [`Line2D`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Line2D.html):

> This class, like all of the Java 2D API, uses a default coordinate system called *user space* in which the y-axis values increase downward and x-axis values increase to the right.

Your rectangle is built using the corner coordinates:

- `(2,7)` - top left
- `(7,7)` - top right
- `(7,8)` - bottom right
- `(2,8)` - bottom left

This means that you line `(4,8) -> (1,8)` intersects your rectangle on the path `(2,8) -> (4,8)` (the left part of the bottom edge/line of the rectangle).

Answer (score 1):

Reading upon java awt package says these :

```
The X values increase to the right, and Y coordinate values increase as they go down.
```

The coordinate system increased towards the bottom. And `2,7` forms the `upper left` point. Thus it will intersect a line that goes from `(4,8) to (1,8)` which forms below the rectangle (***visually***)

Comment: Since you mentioned ```java.awt package ``` I'd believe the rectangle to intersect and there's no bug